# moving numbers into memory using nasm

Tags: assembly, nasm

I am new to `nasm` programming. I want to store integer values in variables

```
SECTION .bss
    temp:      RESB    8

SECTION .text

global  _start

_start:

    mov eax,4
    mov [temp],eax
```

This will move my `integer` value to start of temp location. But I want to move it into the `2nd location`. As integer occupies 2 bytes, I want to store `4` not at the start but at the next position i.e `temp+2`. How can  I do that? Also, when retrieving back the value, how will I be able to retrieve from just the `temp+2` location assuming I have 4 integer in temp each occupying 2 bytes.

Comment: There's no need to go through a register when storing an immediate. You can simply say `mov word [temp+2], 4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store a 2-byte integer, use the `ax` register instead of `eax` (`ax` corresponds to the 2 lowest bytes of `eax`).

To store at `temp`+2, store at `temp`+2 :)

So:

```
mov [temp+2], ax
```

You can similarly retrieve the value into just the `ax` register:

```
mov ax, [temp+2]
```

Or you can move with zero-extension or sign-extension into `eax`:

```
movzx eax, word [temp+2]
movsx eax, word [temp+2]
```

(Use the first if the value is unsigned, or the second if it is signed).